# asmack android peer to peer chat also shows 3rd user chat message in chat

Tags: android, chat, asmack, quickblox

I m developing android chat app using `asmack api` with `quickblox`.

I'm facing problem that in peer to peer chat, i also receive 3rd user chat message in my peer chat.

Any hint or help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OnMessageReceivedListener check for message received id

```
String messageString = message.getBody();
  String test=message.getFrom();
  if((friendID+"/Smack").equals(message.getFrom()))
  {

  }
```

where friend-ID is the id , to which you are connected.

Comment: private MyChatController.OnMessageReceivedListener onMessageReceivedListener = new JoinRoom.OnMessageReceivedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onMessageReceived(final Message message) {
          String messageString = message.getBody();
          
          String test=message.getFrom();
         
          if((messageFrom+"/Smack").equals(message.getFrom()))
          {
           
           showMessage(messageString, false);
           
         
          
         
      }
  };

Comment: Thanks Igor,
Please don't forget to mark the answer if will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check to which user this message and filter if this message from other users, but not from you current opponent

Comment: As i m new to android asmack api, quickblox and chating concept. Pls can u guide me proper way of implementation for same. I followed Quickblox demo app but regarding this problem, i coudnt get any hint.

Comment: I need to develop peer to peer chat application. just like whatsapp. Where i can see my friends in list n if chat window is not open then in list & during chat with X user in chat window only X user's message at a time.